# How to use a jquery function for multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a jquery function used to prevent a double clicks on a button and works well.  I want to use the same function for the other button on the other tab (same page).  I tried couple ways and it doesn't work.  Here is my code
Jquery:

```
     var isSubmitted = false; 
    function preventMultipleSubmissions() {

        if (!isSubmitted) { 
            $('#<%=cmdSave1.ClientID %>').val('Submitting.. Please Wait..');                
                isSubmitted = true; 
                return true; 
            } 
            else { 
                return false; 
            }
```

My .aspx page:

```
   <asp:Button ID="cmdSave1" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Save" 
                      OnClientClick="return preventMultipleSubmissions();"
                     OnClick="cmdSaveEmergency_Click"></asp:Button>   

   <asp:Button ID="cmdSave2" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Save" 
                      OnClientClick="return preventMultipleSubmissions();"
                     OnClick="cmdSaveEmergency_Click"></asp:Button>
```

- I tried put in something like:

  ```
  $('#<%=cmdSave1.ClientID %>', '#<%=cmdSave2.ClientID%>') .val('Submitting.. Please Wait..');
  ```

and it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you evaluate your ids value ? As they are set manually, I don't get why you do this.
If you put $('#cmdSave1', '#cmdSave2') ... does it work ?

Comment: Explain **"doesn't work"**.

Comment: When I used the function on cmdSave1, the text "Save" changed to the new text "Submitting...", but when I used tried on both button, the text is not changing, so there is a big chance that the user will hit on the button again that I don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

You could find all submit buttons using JQuery and apply your logic as below.

```
 $(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
            var button = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
            setTimeout(function () {
                showProgress();
                button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }, 0);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it all works well now, I have couple extra quotation between the buttons

```
   $('#<%=cmdSave1.ClientID %>', '#<%=cmdSave2.ClientID%>') .val('Submitting.. Please Wait..');
```

Correct one :

```
   $('#<%=cmdSave1.ClientID %>, #<%=cmdSave2.ClientID%>') .val('Submitting.. Please Wait..');
```

Thank you all.